# JApplet in appletviewer / JRE1.6.0_30 — NullPointerException on getParameter("someArg")

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, japplet, getparameter, appletviewer

Why am I getting a `NullPointerException` when I call `getParameter()` in this very simple `JApplet` instantiation?

```
public class TestPad extends javax.swing.JApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestPad appletDefn = new TestPad();

                TestPad.sSomeParam = (String)appletDefn.getParameter("sSomeParam");

                appletDefn.init();

                appletDefn.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static String sSomeParam = "sSomeArg";

}
```

No security policy file, no other packages, and only two libraries:
a) swing-layout-1.0.4.jar
b) JDK-1.6 (default)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the method in the `Applet` class:

```
 public String getParameter(String name) {
     return stub.getParameter(name);
 }
```

So the method call on `transient private AppletStub stub` throws the exception.
Applets have an other lifecycle than a normal application. I suggest you to take a look at the [official Java tutorials on Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/).

Answer (score 1):

1. That code throws no NPE when run in the applet viewer here.  This is no surprise to me, since it would load the public applet class, then invoke `init()` and `run()`.  At no time would it call the `main(String[])`.
2. Which leads me to the conclusion that you are running the 'applet' by calling the `main(String[])`, not using the applet viewer.  Running it that way ***will*** cause an NPE because there has been no applet context/stub set up and initialized.  It takes some work to do so.